# ActiveRecord::Relation convert to hash slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

i query ***5000*** records from the database, then converted into Hash, 'marker_id' as key, if 'marker_id' is the same, put together into Array. but it very slow when convert to Hash.

```
      total_attrs=MarkerAttr.where(marker_layer_id: layer.id)
      temp_attrs={}
      t=Time.now

      for ta in total_attrs
        if !temp_attrs.has_key?(ta.marker_id)
          temp_attrs["#{ta.marker_id}"]=[]
        end
        temp_attrs["#{ta.marker_id}"].push(ta)
      end
      p "to_hash_time::#{Time.now-t}"
      # TODO:: to_hash_time::1.563641124
```

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your loop is slow rather than instantiating 5000 model instances? Keep in mind that `MarkerAttr.where(...)` doesn't actually touch the database, the database gets touched when you try to access the query results (i.e. when your loop starts). Anyway, what are you doing that makes you think you need to pull 5000 models out of the database?

Comment: @muistooshort yes, loop is very slow, and in loop not query logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I'm wondering if Enumerable#group_by will be any faster. Try this:

```
 total_attrs = MarkerAttr.where(marker_layer_id: layer.id).all
 temp_attrs = total_attrs.group_by(&:marker_id)
```

Comment: it can do that,but also very slow. it costs "1.802384381"

Comment: @scottxu Still slow because the problem isn't the grouping, the problem is that you're both instantiating 5000 models.

Comment: oh, what should I do to improve this? thanks a lot.@muistooshort

Comment: I totally agree with @muistooshort that instantiating 5000 objects in one go is not a good idea. Even if you manage to get that faster, the grouping will also take some time. Assuming that you're doing this for some kind of reporting, you can probably make this better by not loading AR objects and loading values in arrays instead.

Comment: Or almost certainly better, do it all inside the database in SQL.